# Find equation roots

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, approximation

I am a software developer and I have made a Java class that solves general equations. I thought that I could use the [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) which is pretty good but of course I have to set up the bounds. Let me explain better.

1. The user inputs a function such as `f(x) = x^3 - x/(x+2) + cos(x)`. The plot of this function is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cqhC.png)
2. The user must input the bounds in which he thinks that there will be a root (where the function intersects with the x axis). Let's say that we have chosen the interval `[-3, 0]`
3. Now I am going to start a loop in which I create a lot of sub-intervals for example `[-3 ; -2.8]`, `[-2.8 ; -2.6]`, `[-2.6 ; -2.4]` and so on. In this way I am able to find the interval in which I have a solution because I just have to check where the sign of the function changes (Bolzano's theorem for roots).

   4. I apply Newton's method in the chosen interval and I get an approx. value of the roots.

The implementation you have seen above is the best that I could imagine. Basically first I need to generate a lot of intervals and then where I am sure that I have a solution, I apply the method.

We assume that the function in each interval is continuous

---

**Question**. Newton's method is fast and pretty good, but my program is slow due to the generation of intervals. What I am asking: is there a better method?

Note that I am not asking suggestions about the code. I would like to know if there is a best approach that I could use to solve equations in general, not only polynomials.

In particular I have made a lot of researches on this topic because my goal is to be able to solve equations **without** putting the bounds. In the case above I was forces to set an interval in which I had to look for the solutions. Is there something that could help me?

Comment: You want to solve equations without putting the bounds: then you almost certainly have to live with the possibility of **failing to find the root**. (That is a [fundamental distinction between open and closed root finding methods](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys317/lectures/open_root/open_root.html).) In that case you should just make a random guess and use Newton's Method.

Comment: So methods that don't use bounds exist but they don't assure me a solution?

Comment: Yes. In fact, Newton's Method which you say you used does not require any initial bounds.

Comment: I thought that I could create bounds and use the method where the function changes sign so I am sure that I'll find a solution. If I applied Newton withoud intervals I have high probabilities to not converge? I have to set a starting point for Newton

Comment: side note, you don't need an initial bound for newton's method but an initial point. If you want to find all n roots of an equation you need to find at **least** n initial points which converge to n distinct roots.

Comment: If you produce a plot, then you already have computed a rather finely grained function table. Scan that table for small values or sign changes, this will give you your initial intervals "for free".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia article is very good for talking about the mathematical reasons why newton's method [fails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Failure_analysis). I would check for multiple roots and your implementation if you feel that your code is not very fast. You should try finding the roots of $$f(x)= 2 \log(x) + \sqrt{x} -2 $$ and $$g(x)=(x-1)^6 .$$ Because of the multiple roots convergence should be much faster for $f$ than $g$. If you don't want your users to provide a interval what you should do is try a random number of initial points (in the domain of the given function). After a sufficient number of random initial points there is a high likely hood that all roots have been found.

Of course you should also tell you users to only input continuous functions as well.

If you need a method that will always find a root for an interval see the [BiSection Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) (you may still need to find multiple intervals if there are multiple roots to your equation, but bisection always gives at least one root if it exists).

Comment: So it seems that the best option is using Newton with random points or bisection in a interval?

Comment: Yes, but also look up the regula falsi method. Which is a hybrid method that is faster that bisection and always converges (it is still slower than newton's method).

Comment: Also see the methods listed under the root finding section here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/optimize.html also you should look up brent's method (another hybrid method).

Comment: What's the problem with $2\log x + \sqrt{x} - 2 = 0$?

Comment: Nothing (if you have a good root finding method), it has one real root that is difficult to find if you are not using a numerical method. This root is also singular and not multiple (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Behavior_of_a_polynomial_function_near_a_multiple_root).